# Python: Appending a 2D list to another 2D list

Tags: python, list, append

I am trying to append a 2D list to another 2D list as follows:

```
list1 = [('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')]
list2 = [('d', '4'), ('e', '5'), ('f', '6')]
```

If I append `list1` to `list2` should output:

```
list2 = [('d', '4'), ('e', '5'), ('f', '6'), ('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')]
```

I have tried to solve the problem with the following code:

```
for x, y in list1:
    list2.append([x, y])
```

Which has given me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python27\SortCounty.py", line 59, in <module>
        for x, y in final_list:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: Please show us the actual inputs and code you are using. You are showing is `list1` and `list2`, while your traceback talks about `final_list`. For the input and code you've shown, you should not get any errors. There's something in either your code or your inputs that you're not showing us, which is going to severely hinder our ability to help

Comment: The code you posted does not produce the error you are reporting. The error message suggests that your actual input contains sequences of more than 2 elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple, use `+` operator. You could concatenate two lists using `+` operator.

```
>>> list1 = [('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')]
>>> list2 = [('d', '4'), ('e', '5'), ('f', '6')]
>>> list2 + list1
[('d', '4'), ('e', '5'), ('f', '6'), ('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')]
```

Comment: Would `list2 += list1` be a valid operation?

Comment: @CMac: yes, it would be

Comment: list .extend is better, but will modify the list

Answer (score 4):

You can use `extend` to modify `list2` inplace:

```
>>> list2.extend(list1)
>>> list2
[('d', '4'), ('e', '5'), ('f', '6'), ('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')]
```

This is particularly efficient if you're extending a large list, since no copy of that list is made: the operation is [`O(k)` in complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), where `k` is the length of the list you're adding on.

This is essentially the same behaviour as the code in your question that, as others have pointed out, should work. In practice `extend` should be a little faster because the loop over `list1` is moved down to C level.

`ValueError: too many values to unpack` indicates that one or more of the tuples in your list `final_list` has more than two elements. This causes the line `for x, y in final_list:` to raise the error since `x` and `y` can't label every element in the tuple.

Comment: Wasn't me buddy. Looks like a good answer as well so not sure why someone would downvote it

Comment: Note: `extend` works with any iterable. If you known that you are working with `list`s than doing `list2 += list1` is exactly equivalent to calling `extend` (in fact it should be a really tiny amount faster since it avoids a lookup).

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you should simply use `extend` method :

```
list2.extend(list1)
```

Your lists are indeed 2d lists, but the result you want does not depend on that. So a simple `extend` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

`('a','1')` in `list1` is a single element

```
In [1]: list1 = [('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')]

In [2]: list2 = [('d', '4'), ('e', '5'), ('f', '6')]

In [3]: for i in list1:
   ...:     list2.append(i)
   ...:     

In [4]: list2
Out[4]: [('d', '4'), ('e', '5'), ('f', '6'), ('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')]
```